# Possible to use UIKit in EAGLView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es

Is it possible to use the `UIKit` classes in `EAGLView`?

For instance, would it somehow be possible to use `UIScrollView` in `EAGLView`, or would you need to reimplement something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know EAGLView is a `UIView` so I would say **YES**

```
Abstract: The EAGLView class is a UIView subclass ....
```

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLES2Sample/Listings/Classes_EAGLView_h.html)

Comment: I actually meant if it is possible to use the features in the scrollview in 3D space. But as I read my question again, you are answering it correctly, so I make this the answer :)